# How to emulate middle-click on two-finger tap on a Synaptics touchpad?

Tags: drivers, mouse, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

I have a Synaptics touchpad whose whole surface is clickable (so the whole surface physically moves down). In windows, I can configure it so pressing the pad with two fingers works like right-click and tapping the pad with two fingers works as middle-click. How can I configure it this way in Ubuntu 13.04?